# Writing DOM elements to the browser console in Nightmare

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, nightmare

I'm using NightmareJS for headless browsing. My code looks like this:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var google = new Nightmare()
    .goto('http://www.google.com')
    .wait(3000)
    .inject('js', 'jquery.min.js')
    .screenshot('screenshot.png')
    .evaluate(function(){
        return $('#footer').html();
    }, function(value){
        console.log(value);
    })
    .run(function(err){
        console.log('All done!');
    });
```

I need to debug DOM elements often using `console.log`. However, `console.log` does not seem to work inside the *.evaluate* block.

How do I log stuff inside *.evaluate* to the console?

Comment: What version of Nightmare are you using?

Comment: 2.1.0. I was able to solve this though; I just forgot to add my answer, but I've done that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve this earlier using Promises. Here's the updated code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;

var nightmare = new Nightmare();
Promise.resolve(nightmare
    .goto('http://www.google.com')
    .wait(3000)
    .inject('js', 'jquery.min.js')
    .screenshot('screenshot.png')
    .evaluate(function(){
        return $('#footer').html();
    }))
    .then(function(value){
        console.log(value);
        console.log('All Done!');
        return nightmare.end();
    })
    .then(function(result){
    }, function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Remember to `npm install es6-promise`. You can also use other Javascript Promises implementations besides the one I used here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, If you're going to use `es6-promises`, you may want to use the `.polyfill()` method instead.  _Edit:_ got the question streams crossed on Node versions, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` works fine inside of the page context (inside of `evaluate()`), but you have to listen to it:

```
new Nightmare()
    .on("consoleMessage", function(msg){
        console.log("remote> " + msg);
    })
    .goto('http://www.google.com')
    .evaluate(function(){
        console.log($('#footer').html());
    }, function(){})
    ...
```

Keep in mind that you can't just fully output DOM nodes to the console like you would in the developer tools of your favorite browser. It would be too much. You have to print a *representation* of the DOM node which you have to build yourself.

You can also use all other events that [PhantomJS provides](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/) in the same way, but this only works for Nightmare versions prior to 2.x, because from version 2.x onward Electron is used as the underlying browser and not PhantomJS.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work though. I tried a simple `console.log('page_scope')` and I didn't see it in the console; all I got was 'All done'.